# In a domain, how does one transfer files from one PC to another?

Tags: domain, file-transfer

I googled it and all I got was how to transfer files from one domain to another domain.

Say I have two PCs, one running windows server 2008 and the other running Windows 7, they're connected via a LAN, and they're part of the same domain.

How do you send a file from one PC to the other?

Why the heck isn't there some simple function where you right click a file and select **send**?

Comment: Via a UNC share name or mapped drive.  e.g. From Server1 you connect to the "Documents" share on "Client1" via the path `\\Client1\Documents`

Comment: That question explain how to make the file shareable not how the other computer will get it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the computers in the same LAN and Domain, it's pretty easy.

1. Share a folder on the destination system using Right mouse-click -> Share with... (or Properties -> Sharing - for more advanced options).
2. Connect to that folder from the source system.
   I like to just do:

   Start -> Run -> \\DESTINATION-SYSTEM-NAME

For instance Start -> Run -> \\Q7D opened this window:
[image: Shared folders on network host Q7D]

You will see the shared folder and can open it or map a drive letter to it.

Then use a command line copy or drag and drop to copy the file.

If you have a drive letter mapped to a shared folder you can use Right Click on a file and Send to.[image]

Comment: I got the first step. But I don't understand the second one. What's "DESTINATION-SYSTEM-NAME" and is there a simpler way to get the file without using RUN and CMD?

Comment: DESTINATION-SYSTEM-NAME is the hostname (computer name) of the destination system.

For instance one of mine is called Q7D so Start -> Run -> \\Q7D opens a window showing the shared folders on that system.

You *may* be able to see the system from the Network icon in the left side of explorer windows.

Comment: Added screenshot showing system "Q7D" in my network with its shares. This is displayed either with the Start -> Run -> \\Q7D command *OR* by browsing the Network as shown on the left side.